Page Builder Content Not Visible After Migration: How to Troubleshoot?
Earlier, I hosted a wordpress website on GoDaddy and recently migrated it to another domain within the same hosting for testing purposes. However, after the migration, the page builder content is not displaying. I'm using BeTheme along with its built-in page builder. Could someone please suggest how to resolve this issue and make the content visible again?
I've tried deactivating all plugins to identify the issue and also tested the site on multiple hosts, and I've migarte through plugins and also manually, but the problem persists.
and inside the error log file there is a warning:

[14-Oct-2024 19:33:49 UTC] PHP Warning: Undefined array key "user-can-close-top-bar" in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/codebulls-top-bar/includes/generate-top-bar.php on line 8

I've removed the plugin but not fixed the problem
